# Printer status is not updating, so it won't print after update to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, samsung

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit (upgraded from 12.04), Samsung ML-2015 (ML-2010). When I first send printing job to the printer, it prints okay, but then printer status still says "Sending data to printer", while printer has already printed page and is available for new jobs. Or status might read "Wainting for printer to become available", while it is available.

It uses CUPS stock PPD driver. There are two of them, I've tried both, no luck. The only way you can make printer status update is either to wait around ten minutes, or to change usb port printer connected to.

It seems to be somehow related to apparomor, as at times when printer is being used I get these lines in /var/log/syslog:

```
Jun 15 13:24:55 ... kernel: [  827.574712] type=1400 audit(1402824295.658:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1055 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
Jun 15 13:24:55 ... kernel: [  827.574740] type=1400 audit(1402824295.658:37): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1055 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
Jun 15 13:24:55 ... kernel: [  827.574758] type=1400 audit(1402824295.658:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1055 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
```

Also, I've tried to monitor logs and there is some interesting activity as you send new job to the printer:

```
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.349170] usb 2-1.2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.443009] usb 2-1.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 31
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.443353] usblp0: removed
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... udev-configure-printer: remove /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.3
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.517355] usb 2-1.2.3: new full-speed USB device number 32 using ehci-pci
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.611263] usb 2-1.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=326c
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.611274] usb 2-1.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.611281] usb 2-1.2.3: Product: Samsung ML-2010
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.611286] usb 2-1.2.3: Manufacturer: Samsung
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.611291] usb 2-1.2.3: SerialNumber: 3D66BKCP824986L.
Jun 15 14:34:37 ... kernel: [ 5014.612787] usblp 2-1.2.3:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 32 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04E8 pid 0x326C
Jun 15 14:34:38 ... udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.3/2-1.2.3:1.0
Jun 15 14:34:38 ... udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.3/2-1.2.3:1.0
Jun 15 14:34:38 ... udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
```

This repeats every 5 seconds. That is, every five seconds some process resets printer USB device via ehci-pci and then it disappears and appears again.

Answer (score 0):

First run this command:

```
lspci | grep USB
```

you will get IDs like: 000:00:1a.0, 0000:00:1d.0

Then type these commands:

```
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/bind
```

This will restart or reset USB in your Ubuntu. Now, try plugging in your printer again.

Comment: `tee: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind: No such file or directory`

And what does it supposed to do? The problem is, rebooting does not help - that is, resetting USB won't help either.