# How to update printer state after installing cups file

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am using a Canon MP210 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11 printer, which is showing the status "Stopped - File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.2" not available: No such file or directory" when I check under printer properties. Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819561/ubuntu-16-04-missing-cups-file) I installed printer-driver-gutenprint, and I have restarted the computer and confirmed that the file it is asking for is there. Despite this, the printer status has not changed, and the printer will not print. What can I do to update the printer status so that it finds the file I installed?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to unplug the printer and plug it back in again. Go figure. Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483538/printer-status-is-not-updating-so-it-wont-print-after-update-to-ubuntu-14-04) for the inspiration.